# Updating <h:panelGroup> from another <h:panelGroup> not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a code like:

```
<h:panelGroup id="customListCal">
..
      <p:commandButton value="Create List" update="pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.openList}"
                        style="background:#25A6E1;color:#fff;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="pickList">
..
   <p:commandButton value="Cancel" update="pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.closeList}" style="background:#25A6E1;color:red;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;" />
   <p:commandButton value="Save" update="custDataTablePanel pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.saveTargetList}" style="background:#25A6E1;color:red;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;"/>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup  id="custDataTablePanel">
   <p:panel rendered="#{customCalender.dataTableVisible}">
        <p:dataTable id="custDataTable" value="#{customCalender.dataTableList}" var="listName">
              <p:column id="editField" headerText="Edit">
                            <p:commandLink title="Edit"  update="pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.openList}" rendered="#{not empty customCalender.dataTableList}">
                                <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/edit.JPG"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
              </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
   </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

when I try to update `<h:panelGroup id="pickList">` from `<h:panelGroup id="custDataTablePanel>` its not working. What happen is just this coloumn named `Edit` is not rendered in the said dataTable.

How can I update `<h:panelGroup id="pickList">` from `<h:panelGroup id="custDataTable">`?

But there is no error in updating `<h:panelGroup id="pickList">` from `<h:panelGroup id="customListCal"`>

```
<h:panelGroup id="customListCal">
..
      <p:commandButton value="Create List" update="pickList" actionListener="#{customCalender.openList}"
                        style="background:#25A6E1;color:#fff;font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;font-size:10px;border-radius:4px;"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: make sure that the `p:commandButton` is inside a `h:form`

Comment: @Daniel: its inside the `<h:form>` tag.. :(

Comment: are `picklist` and `custDataTable` inside the same form?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes they are..

Comment: The `<h:panelGroup id="pickList">` can be updated from `<h:panelGroup id="customListCal">` but not from the command button within `<h:panelGroup id="custDataTablePanel">`.

Why is that so?

Comment: try to use the full element name e.g. `update=":form1:picklist"`

Comment: @fareed: Tried this before! :(

Comment: what version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: @fareed: its version:3.4.2

Comment: what is the scope of customCalender?

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue in Primefaces prior to version 3.4. But since you have a 3.4, then my only suggestion is to use a core JSF button instead of primefaces button.

```
<h:commandButton>
   <f:ajax render="element"> <!--or render=":form1:element"-->
</h:commandButton>
```

instead of

```
<p:commandButton update ="element">
```

Comment: But its a `<p:commandLink>` I am using here in the `<h:panelGroup id="custDataTablePanel">`

Comment: You can use `<h:commandLink>` which has the same functionality